# TableView Custom Cell UIButton Action

Tags: ios4

I am using CustomCell in my tableView.With few buttons and labels. Now I want to give some actions in those buttons.Can anyone help me how can I use Action for my UIButton?

in the interface :

```
-(IBAction)btnAction;
```

in the implementation :

```
-(IBAction)btnAction
{
    [self Evaluate:(int *)1 :(int *)2]; 
}
```

Now tell me how can I assign the action in a UIButton?I have UIButton in my cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically add an action to the UIButton using the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method (a method of UIControl, of which UIButton is a subclass).

So your implementation would look something like:

```
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(btnAction)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @StuDev : I have BeginingCell.h and BeginingCell.m for the CustomCell.And i am using it in the GameTableView(another Class).Where should id put those code?

Comment: @sohel_14_cse_ju: If I understand correctly, I would say that a good approach would be to save an outlet to your UIButton in the BeginingCell class (using an @property declaration, and @synthesize to generate the accessor/mutator), so that you can access it from your GameTableView. Then when you initialise your cells from within your GameTableView, you would do something like `[myBeginningCell.theButton addTarget:action:forControlEvents]` (assuming your button property inside BeginingCell.h was called `theButton`).

Comment: my outlet are defined in the beginingCell.It's alright according to your guidance.I was just trying something like this   [BeginingCellObject.ansBtn1 addTarget:btnAnsEval:forControlEvents]; Having error with the btnAnsEval Method.It's showing it's not declared.But i did it properly in the tableView class.Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @StuDev : getting error that forControlEvents was undclared in :[BeginingCellObject.ansBtn1 addTarget:self.actn:forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; this line....

Comment: @sohel_14_cse_ju: The full method name is `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. It looks like you are trying to do `addTarget:forControlEvents`. Targets & actions are assigned in pairs - the target is the object / class containing the action method. In `forControlEvents:` you need to specify when this action will be called. In my example above, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` specifies that the action will be called upon the user lifting their finger up from inside a button.